# CS50 Pset3 music final calculation

Tags: c, cs50

I'm trying to understand why my final calculation for the Frequency part of this Pset is not calculating properly. I'm going through the debugger, and it shows that the "steps" is counting correctly, but the calculation doesn't work.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
   string note = get_string("note:");
   {
      if (strlen(note) == 2)
      {
         int key = note[0];
         int octave = atoi(&note[1]);
         int steps = 0;

         if(key == 'A')
            {
               steps = (key - 65) + ((octave - 4) * 12);
            }

         float frequencyf = (440 * (pow(2, (steps / 12))));
         int frequency = (round(frequencyf));
         printf("%i", frequency);
      }

      else if (strlen(note) == 3)
      {
         int key = note[0];
         int accidental = note[1];
         int octave = atoi(&note[2]);
         int steps = 0;

         if(accidental == '#')
           {
               if(key == 'A')
               {
                  steps = ((key - 65) + ((octave - 4) * 12) + 1);
               }
            }
        else if(accidental == 'b')
            {
               if(key == 'A')
               {
                  steps = ((key - 65) + ((octave - 4) * 12) - 1);
               }
            }

         float frequencyf = (440 * (pow(2, (steps / 12))));
         int frequency = (round(frequencyf));
         printf("%i", frequency);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: There's a [cs50 stack exchange site](https://cs50.stackexchange.com/) if you're interested.

Comment: ah didnt see that sorry!

Comment: Remember that in C, integer division yields an integer result: `1/2 == 0`, `5/2 == 2`, etc.  If you want the result of the division to be a floating point value, at least one of the operands must be a floating point type.  Try dividing `steps` by `12.0` and see if that doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

In the problem, The standard pitch of A4 is 440 Hz. since we are starting at A4 key, we create an array of semitones and find the tone value from ASCII:

```
A  B  C  D  E  F  G
0  2 -9 -7 -5 -4 -2

int semitones[] = {0, 2, -9, -7, -5, -4, -2};
float tone = semitones[note[0] - 'A'];
```

The accidentals `#` or `b` raise or lower the note by one semitone. But we're not sure where the octave is in the note and we also need to find its difference from the 4th octave. There are different scenarios so a switch statement works well:

```
int octave;
switch(note[1])
{
    case '#':
        tone++;
        octave = note[2];
        break;
    case 'b':
        tone--;
        octave = note[2];
        break;
    default:
        octave = note[1];
        break;
}
octave -= '4';
```

The frequencies of an octave is a factor of 2. A3 will be 220 Hz while A5 will be 880 Hz. So

```
if (octave > 0)
    hz *= octave * 2;
else if (octave < 0)
    hz /= abs(octave * 2);
```

Finally, the frequency of a note is 2^(n/12) where n is number of semitones from A4:

```
if (tone < 0)
{
    tone *= -1;
    hz /= pow(2, tone / 12);
}
else if (tone > 0)
    hz *= pow(2, tone / 12);
```